# Microsoft.UI.Xaml compatibility issues

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, nuget, nuget-package

I want compatibility for my app on all Windows 10 versions, but use fluent design when Anniversary Update or above. However, the Microsoft.UI.Xaml NuGet package throwing Target version error, which I solved with SkipMicrosoftUIXamlCheckTargetPlatformVersion tag. But now I still getting errors now from Visual Studio, how to skip that?

> Error: Your application is taking a dependency on a framework package
>   that has a TargetPlatformMinVersion that is higher than what your app
>   is depending on. Change your app manifest to make sure the
>   TargetPlafromMinVersion of your app’s dependencies is greater than or
>   equal to the framework’s TargetPlatformMinVersion.
>   TargetPlatformIdentifier: 'Windows.Universal'. Application's
>   TargetPlatformVersion: '10.0.10240.0'. Dependent framework's
>   TargetPlatformVersion: '10.0.14393.0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: Your application is taking a dependency on a framework package that has a TargetPlatformMinVersion that is higher than what your app is depending on.

Even though you could edit the following error, but the minimum  dependency version of  framework package is `10.0.14393.0`. You could not modify the following to change all the
dependencies version.

```
<Error 
    Text="Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformMinVersion &gt;= 10.0.14393.0 (current project is $(MicrosoftUIXamlTargetPlatformMinCheckValue))"
    Condition="$(MicrosoftUIXamlTargetPlatformMinCheckValue) &lt; 14393" />
```

Derive from official [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml#version-support).

> The Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.1 NuGet package requires your project to have TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.17763.0 and TargetPlatformMinVersion >= 10.0.14393.0 when building.
>
> Your app's users can be on any of the following supported Windows versions:
> Windows Insider Previews
> May 2019 Update (18362)
> October 2018 Update (17763)
> April 2018 Update (17134)
> Fall Creators Update (16299)
> Creators Update (15063)
> Anniversary Update (14393)

Please modify the app's target mini version as Anniversary Update (14393).

Comment: My friend, how you modify app's target mini version as AU? Could you please explain it?

Comment: You could right click your project and click properties option, it contains min version edit area in the property application tab.